# Can't ping wordpress.org

Tags: ping, wordpress

I come to solicit your help on a simple problem but for which I can't find any solution at the moment.

Indeed, since my dedicated server (under ubuntu 17.04) it is impossible for me to ping the site wordpress.org.

During a ping I find myself with the following answer: "Destination Port Unreachable".

If I try to connect to this same address from lynx: "Alert !: Unable to connect to remote host."

No problem with all the other sites I've tested, only wordpress.org doesn't seem to want to work.

An idea? or suggestion?

Comment: Why would you like to ping WordPress.org?

Comment: It's just a ping test, my problem is i can't connect to api.wordpress.org from my dedicated server so i can't use some functionnalities. So I was just doing a ping test to try to find out more.